# ENOENT error using nodejs on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, railway.js

I'm getting an ENOENT error on my heroku app, preventing it from starting up:

Error: ENOENT, open '/app/log/production.log'

This file / dir (app/log) does exist however...
So I'm not sure what's going on?

Comment: Not a strong opinion but, If that directory is empty in the beginning, git may not have added it to the commit so maybe directory is not present in the heroku? just a guess

Comment: yeah.. that was a suggestion i had... however- i force added it to git, pushed, still no luck. what i ended up doing was     app.disable('quiet'); - stop writing to log file

Comment: I have encountered this same error when the /tmp or /log directories are absent or present but empty, and gets committed from the git repo.  The solution I've found is to create a README file in the directory and add that to git.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up disabling 'quiet' mode to stop writing logs to disk:

```
app.disable('quiet');
```

This seems to of resolved it