# Change to STDOUT logging on nodejs app

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

Following on from this:
[ENOENT error using nodejs on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196057/enoent-error-using-nodejs-on-heroku)

I've been suggested to use STDOUT logging on my node.js app...?
Is this possible?
If so, how / where do I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to:
[ENOENT error using nodejs on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196057/enoent-error-using-nodejs-on-heroku/10201055#10201055)

I ended up disabling 'quiet' mode to stop writing logs to disk:

app.disable('quiet');
This seems to of resolved it